# Scala map creation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to create a map with 10000 elements but all elements should be the same.

So I want a map look like this: `[(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)...]`. I know how to specify a range of values and then create a map out of it, but how can I use the same duplicate values?

Follow up question:

What is the difference between the `RDD[(Int, Int)]` and `List[(Int, Int)]`? I am doing:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = (1 to 10).map(i => (1,1)).toList
```

but I get a type mismatch error.
I want a `RDD[(Int, Int)]` with the contents I mentioned, how can I do that?

Comment: There are more differences between `RDD[A]` and `List[A]` then there are similarities. The only thing that they have in common is that they are Monad-like collections of entities. And you are getting that error for the same reason as the error in these -> `val i: Int = "abcd"` or `val a: List[Int] = Option(5)` and that is - the types of your variable and reference value are incompatible with each-other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A map by its very definition cannot have more than one element with the same key. Based on what you said that you wanted, I'm guessing you're looking for a list of tuples. This would be something along the lines of `(1 to 10000).map(i => (1,1)).toList`

Answer (score 1):

Maps can contain only one entry with any particular key. Assuming you meant a list, then

```
List.fill(10000)((1,1))
```

will do it.

A List is a data structure kept locally. A RDD is distributed across multiple nodes. Quite different but they have a lot of the same methods (as a deliberate choice by the Spark designers). You can convert a List to an RDD like tthis...

```
val sc = ... // Spark Context
val myList  = ....
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(myList)
```

But a question this basic suggests you may benefit from reading an introductory tutorial on Spark, as it's one of the first things typically covered.